# Django objects.filter() issues

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

My Django project contains an application called: app_1
It stores models.py file which contains a Django models called: client
I cannot filter my models throw client.objects.filter(nom=something), Django search into a wrong relation it just add my app name with my model's name and search into "app_1_client" (it should be in "client")
ERREUR:  the relation « app_1_client » doesn't exist

I can access my data with client.objects.raw(""" query """)

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class client(models.Model):
    nom = models.CharField(max_length = 100, null=False)
    prenom = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)
    tel = models.CharField(max_length=12, primary_key=True)
```

views.py

```
from .models import client
def modify_client(request, client_phone):
    c = client.objects.filter(pk=client_phone)
    context = {'clients': c}
```

Comment: Did you manually create a database table?

Comment: Yes i did in pg admin, but I also have migrate my models and data in python

Comment: As an aside, the model is pretty terrible – are you sure you don't want your clients to be able to change their phone numbers? (In general, Django's automatic integer primary keys work fine, or you could use an UUID or ULID. But a phone number isn't good.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django's table names are of the form `APPNAME_MODELNAME` by default, so it's not at fault here.

The error "the relation « app_1_client » doesn't exist" implies that the table doesn't actually exist in your database, which happens if you haven't run `makemigrations` to create the database migration file that would create that table, and subsequently run `migrate` to actually apply the migration.

Migrations are first explained [here in the Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/intro/tutorial02/#activating-models):

> Migrations are how Django stores changes to your models (and thus your database schema) - they’re files on disk. You can read the migration for your new model if you like; it’s the file polls/migrations/0001_initial.py. Don’t worry, you’re not expected to read them every time Django makes one, but they’re designed to be human-editable in case you want to manually tweak how Django changes things.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer first, I actually runned makemigrations command and I have the 0001_initial.py file and migrate command. I can also see that my table exist and there is data in it, when I run psql command in command line

Comment: What is the name of the existing table? You can use the meta `db_table` option to force a name, but you generally don't need to.

Comment: My table's name is: client. I actually create my table on pg admin manually and added there data, but I also have my models.py and migrate the data. Can it be the problem?

Comment: Yes, that _is_ a problem. Let Django create the table and manage its structure. You can then use your favorite database tool to add data (but maybe also look into Django fixtures and `loaddata` instead).